# Physics without forces

Tags: forces, soft-question

Do there exist theories of physics without the concept of force? For, example, even though we sometimes associate repulsion and/or attraction with the concept of force, can all that be explained without that concept? Can, somehow, all of physics be explained in terms of fields and continuous and, possibly, discontinuous changes and processes in only the fields themselves?

Comment: Yes. There are many theoretical frameworks. Are you interested in classical physics or in more general cases?

Comment: @user1420303 In every case, in all the cases.

Comment: You can start looking for Lagrangian and hamiltonian mechanics, Hamilton-Jacobi equation and quantum mechanics in its more common formulations. There are others alternatives.

Comment: Quantum field theory doesn’t tend to talk about force, and it explains elementary particles and their strong, weak, and electromagnetic interactions in terms of quantum fields. (There is an electron field, a photon field, a quark field, etc.)  General Relativity doesn’t tend to talk about force, and it explains gravity in terms of a non-quantum field that determines spacetime geometry. Modern fundamental physics is pretty much all about fields.

Comment: I think energy can be used to explain physics without forces but energy in itself is derived from forces.

Comment: @G.Smith What are the differences between classical and quantum fields?

Comment: The value of a classical field at a point is just a number (or a set of related numbers such as a vector or a tensor). There are various ways to formulate quantum field theory, but in one common formulation the value of a quantum field at a point is an *operator* (or a set of operators). This is similar to how in basic quantum *mechanics* quantities like energy become operators. In a quantum field theory, the field operators operate on multiparticle states in something called a Fock space. So a quantum field can describe the creation and annihilation of particles. A classical field cannot.

Comment: @G.Smith I have some questions, should we chat in some chat-room, if you are willing to write me the answers?

Comment: Unfortunately, you need a reputation of 20 or higher to use PSE’s chat.

Comment: I suggest that you post your questions on the site so that other people besides me can perhaps answer them.